# Extract title of nested json using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
{
  "Ankle" : {
    "1544095214100" : {
      "AX" : -0.3310394287109375,
      "AY" : -0.3018035888671875,
      "AZ" : 9.595489501953125
    },
    "1544095214200" : {
      "AX" : -0.3290557861328125,
      "AY" : -0.2254791259765625,
      "AZ" : 9.609939575195312
    },
    "1544095214500" : {
      "AX" : -0.32763671875,
      "AY" : -0.22491455078125,
      "AZ" : 9.612503051757812
    }
  } ,
  "Head" : {
    "1544095207100" : {
      "AX" : -0.32867431640625,
      "AY" : -0.2235870361328125,
      "AZ" : 9.608489990234375
    },
```

Currently my JSON file looks like this. I am using pandas and I would like to extract all the timestamp values (i.e: 1544095214100) from "Ankles" and add them to an array. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure why you'd use pandas for such a trivial task. `d['Ankle'].keys()` will give you `dict_keys(['1544095214100', '1544095214200', '1544095214500'])`

Comment: @DeepSpace I want to make a graph having X value as the timestamp and Y the AX, AY or AZ value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do more with `Anker` and find out `Math.sqrt`, do following:

```
myList = []
for key,value in d['Ankle'].iteritems():
    temp=[key,value]
    myList.append(temp)
```

Now you can traverse `myList` to the 2nd set of ooperations

Try `myList[0]` `myList[0][1]` and `myList[0][1]["AX"]` commands to get the next steps

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

DeepSpace is correct. Dont get too caught  up using libraries like pandas, for this just use Python.

```
d = {
  "Ankle" : {
    "1544095214100" : {
      "AX" : -0.3310394287109375,
      "AY" : -0.3018035888671875,
      "AZ" : 9.595489501953125
    },
    "1544095214200" : {
      "AX" : -0.3290557861328125,
      "AY" : -0.2254791259765625,
      "AZ" : 9.609939575195312
    },
    "1544095214500" : {
      "AX" : -0.32763671875,
      "AY" : -0.22491455078125,
      "AZ" : 9.612503051757812
    }
  } ,
  "Head" : {
    "1544095207100" : {
      "AX" : -0.32867431640625,
      "AY" : -0.2235870361328125,
      "AZ" : 9.608489990234375
    }
  }
}

myList = []
for key in d['Ankle'].keys():
    myList.append(key)

print(myList)
```

So, in the example above, just substitute you array for myList.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my goal is to create a graph from the Ankles class where the X value is the timestamp (i.e: 1544095214100) and the Y values is the result of Math.sqrt(AX^2+AY^2+AZ^2). Am i taking the right approach?